# How to refresh data in a TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `TabbedLayout`. In my *Tab1* and it's activity, I have fields to add a user and stored in a Table. In my *Tab2*, I have a layout which displays all added users from this table.

My problem here is, when I add user in *Tab1*, the data is added into the table. When I move to *Tab2*, then all users excluding this new added user is displayed. But how to refresh this table?

How can I refresh my *Tab2* `onCreateView` when I change Tabs?

I tried with below statements but didnt help.

```
trackerTbl.invalidate();
trackerTbl.refreshDrawableState();
```

Can someone help me how to refresh this table?

Comment: Are you using activity for tabs in Tablayout

Comment: Yes, it is. For both of these tabs, i have two separate layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tab1 when data added successful in table then send broadcast.

```
Intent data_added = new Intent("data_added");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast("data_added");
```

In Tab2 onResume() method write below code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    BroadcastReceiver receiver_insert_customer = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals("data_added")) {
                onResume();
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(YourActivityName.this).registerReceiver(receiver_insert_customer,
            new IntentFilter("data_added"));

    models = new ArrayList<>();
    models = databaseobject.yourmethodfetchdatafromdb();
    adapter = new customAdapter(getApplicationContext(), models);
}
```

Comment: what value i need to specify("data_added") in new Intent("data_added")?

Comment: when we send data using intent that time we use key. "data_added" is key here.

Comment: Here whatever data insertion i am saying, that i am directly inserting using some DBHelpers and invoke a method like insertUser(String,String blaa blaa...). So does your answer applies here?

Comment: Yes you can apply this code.
After inserting user in databse you send broadcast in your code.
Intent data_added = new Intent("data_added");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast("data_added");

In which fragment you want update table, that  fragment will write another code which is written in answer.

Comment: @ Android Hupp, Thanks it helps. But now the challenge i see is, i want to clear off my previous content displayed and just show the latest content.Ex: say i have 3 records which shows onResume. In Tab1, i added another record. Then in my Tab2, it shows first 3 records and then 4 records with newly added record. How can I remove my previous 3 records and just show updated only 4 records.

Comment: Hey Sorry, i got it correct by removingAllViews at the first statement in onResume. Thanks so much for your help Android Hupp.